# second column of a file equals some variables

Tags: unix, awk

If the second column of a file equals one of the number below :

```
65,81,83,97,99,113,129,145,147,161,163,177     #To be read 65 OR 81 OR 83 OR 97 OR 99 etc..
```

then I need to print the whole line in an output file, so typed the following:

```
samtools view myfile.bam | awk '{for (i=65,81,83,97,99,113,129,145,147,161,163,177) if ($2==i) ; print$0} > output.bam
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a `dict` which contains a list of numbers in the `BEGIN` block.
Then use `dict` as a filter.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    dict[65]
    dict[81]
    # skip
    dict[177]
}
$2 in dict' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long list, rather than having a lot of explicit assignments:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    numlist = "65,81,83,97,99,113,129,145,147,161,163,177"
    split(numlist, a, ",")
    for (i in numlist) {
        nums[a[i]]
    }
}
$2 in nums' inputfile
```